# Vue.js v-bind modifier .camel: fail to covert to camelCase

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and have a basic question.

I use the modifier `.camel` and try to convert the attribute name "data-abc-def" (kebab-case) to "dataAbcDef"(camelCase), 
but the result I get is "dataabcdef", i.e., this string is in lowercase, not camelCase.

Following is the code snippet.

```
<div id="app">
  <a href="#" :data-abc-def.camel="id">${ text }</a>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'Hello World！',
    id: '123456789！'
  }
});
```

And the result I get...

[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance using vue-loader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.camel` cannot be applied to arbitrary attributes, which `data-*` attributes are (it works with SVG's `viewBox` attribute; see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gssrzhnc/)).

See [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2250#issuecomment-176378156) by Vue.js creator on an old issue, stating that:

> Hmm, this is annoying because HTML parsing only preserves the camelCase for valid camelCase attributes […]

By the way, this was the issue that initiated the whole `.camel` feature.

In a [later issue response](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5186#issuecomment-286304512), he says:

> Avoid using camelCase when using in-DOM templates.